# Adding relying parties in ADFS using C# or Powershell

Tags: powershell, adfs

I need to add Relying parties in ADFS everytime a new client comes on.  I would like to automate this by just specifying either the url to the federation metadata or a file picker for the admin to load the federation metadata file.

I have been following the instructions on this site [Adding a New Relying Party Trust](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee895353.aspx)

However I get the following error

```
ADMIN0120: The client is not authorized to access the endpoint 
net.tcp://localhost:1500/policy. 
The client process must be run with elevated administrative privileges.
```

not sure what I am doing wrong.  I guess the bigger question is : is this the best way to set up Relying parties and Claims using code or should I use powershell commands?

Answer (score 0):

This error doesn't means you have code issue. It is something related to the privilege. Test it by right mouse click the client and "Run as administrator" to see if it goes through.

Answer (score 0):

As per your link, there are three ways:

- Using the AD FS 2.0 Management console
- Using the Windows PowerShell command-line interface
- Programmatically using the AD FS 2.0 application programming interface (API)

All three are equally valid - the only difference is how much work you have to do for each e.g. the wizard is lots of mouse clicks.

What I do is set up the RP the first time via the wizard and then save the setup using PowerShell (Get RP, Get Claims etc.) and then use these to set up subsequent ones as you migrate from dev. to test. to staging etc.